# Where function in python returns nothing

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have this array

```
     a = array([1,5,7])
```

I apply the where function

```
     where(a==8)
```

What is returned in this case is

```
    (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

However I would like the code to return the integer "0" whenever the where function returns an empty array. Is that possible?

Comment: What would you like it to return when there is a single match, and that match is at index zero?

Comment: Why do you want that? What is good for to have to return types? Why don't make a check of the array size to know if you found it? And then use the array in case it's not emtpy?

Comment: @aix: there is no possible "confusion" problem: if the match is at index 0, the result is `(array([0]),)`, not `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def where0(vec):
    a = where(vec)
    return a if a[0] else 0
    # The return above is equivalent to:
    # if len(a[0]) == 0:
    #     return 0  # or whatever you like
    # else:
    #     return a

a = array([1,5,7])
print where0(a==8)
```

And consider also the comment from *aix* under your question. Instead of fixing `where()`, fix your algorithm

Comment: +1 for the general advice (it is best if functions only have a single return type), but your whole `if len(a[0]) == 0…` structure could be replaced by the much simpler and shorter `return a if a[0] else 0`.

Comment: oh, I use python since long but never used this neat syntax... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better use a function that has only one return type. You can check for the size of the array to know if it's empty or not, that should do the work:

```
 a = array([1,5,7])
 result = where(a==8)

 if result[0] != 0:
     doFancyStuff(result)
 else:
     print "bump"
```

Comment: You probably meant `len(result[0])`?

Comment: I wouldn't use 'is' on integers.  For 0 it works because of the integer cache but a = 10000; a is 10000 is False.  Using '==' avoids this problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Comment: EOL, why would he want to take the len of result[0]?  It's a one-dimensional array...

Comment: @ChadMiller: Thanks for the hint. Fixed it.

Comment: @ChadMiller - "where" does not return an array, it returns a tuple of arrays (see the original question).  Though I think this may have changed from earlier numpy versions.

Comment: @JoeZUntz: correct, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where

Comment: @JoeZuntz Thanks, I missed the ',' at the end of OP's output.

Comment: @ezdazuzena: your `if len(result[0]) != 0` could be more simply written as `if result[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

a empty array will return 0 with .size

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([])    
a.size
>> 0
```

Comment: A brief explanation would improve your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try the below. This will handle the case where a test for equality to 0 will fail when index 0 is returned. (e.g. `np.where(a==1`) in the below case)

```
a = array([1,5,7])
ret = np.where(a==8)
ret = ret if ret[0].size else 0
```