# Numpy where returns empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

I have an array e.g.

```
a = [5,1,3,0,2]
```

I apply the where function:

```
np.where(a == 2)
```

The output is an empty array

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

I found kind of the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002749/where-function-in-python-returns-nothing), but in my case it really dosen't make any sense or dose it?

Btw. i'm on a Mac using Python 2.7.10

Comment: `a` is a list, not a numpy array.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The interpreter first evaluates `a==2`, and then passes the result to the `where` function.  Does that `a==2` make sense?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're passing a list to `where()` function not a Numpy array. Use an array instead:

```
In [20]: a = np.array([5,1,3,0,2])

In [21]: np.where(a == 2)
Out[21]: (array([4]),)
```

Also as mentioned in comments, in this case the value of `a == 2` is `False`, and this is the value passed to `where`. If `a` is a numpy array, then the value of `a == 2` is a numpy array of bools, and the `where` function will give you the desire results.

Comment: Actually, the function is not being applied to a list.  The value of `a == 2` in the question is simply `False`, and this is the value passed to `where`.  But you are correct in that the problem is that `a` is a list and not a numpy array.  If `a` is a numpy array, then the value of `a == 2` is a numpy array of bools, and then `where` works as expected.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Indeed! thanks for point that out, it could cause a miss understanding.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand! Thank you very much for your quick and well explained help!