# np.where is skipping random values in my array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I make an array:

```
X = np.arange(0.001, 1, 0.001)
```

Later I want to find the points in `X` that match a value I pull and format from a dataframe `x1`:

```
index1 = np.where(X == x1)
```

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369104/numpy-where-returns-empty-array), but:

1. `np.arange` produces an `array`
2. `x1` is an `array`

I'm left very confused.

I tried it on a scratch pad in PyCharm:

```
import numpy as np
precision = 3
delta = 10 ** -precision
a = np.arange(delta, 1, delta)
n = np.array([0.070])

print(np.where(a == n))
```

If `n` equals `0.071`, `0.072`, `0.073`, it returns an empty cell. Many values of `n` give me a value and very few produce an error from an empty array.

I want to find all the values I need.

Thanks.

Comment: floating point precision?

Comment: I appreciate the concise response, but I didn't ask a generically simple question, because I am an expert with python, I'm new and learning. Your response doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never<sup>*</sup> use `==` to compare floating point values. Choose a precision value you are comfortable with and check they are within that distance.

Luckily `numpy` has a convenient way of doing this: `np.isclose`.

```
>>> print(np.where(np.isclose(a, n)))
(array([69], dtype=int64),)
```

---

Once you have read and understood [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) you may use `==` on floating point values when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was driving me nuts and I appreciate the document.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @orlp said, you are generating floating point numbers using the np.arrange() function. As you can see below, the number is close to 0.073  but not exactly 0.073.

```
import numpy as np
precision = 3
delta = 10 ** -precision
a = np.arange(delta, 1, delta)
n = np.array([0.073])
print(a[72]) #
print(n)
print(a[72] == n[0])
```

gives the output of

```
0.07300000000000001
[0.073]
False
```

Comment: I see. The value I am looking for in X is formatted to 3 decimals, but not the array itself. Is there a way to produce an array of formatted values?

Comment: You can use `np.round(a,4)` I dont know how optimal this solution it should work.